# Is it safe to publish to IPFS when deploying in Remix?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

Could hackers use the metadata?

Should I redeploy the contract?

Since smart contracts cannot be changed it seems like a bad idea to let people see the source code/meta data despite mine being imported from OpenZeppelin.

Comment: If the contract has an obvious bug perhaps it will be a problem. But bots in ethereum are quite advanced and they can attack contracts without knowing the source. 

Read the article [Ethereum is a Dark Forest](https://medium.com/@danrobinson/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest-ecc5f0505dff) to learn about some of their actions.

It is just a matter of opinion. If the contract is going to hold important funds it is better to make audits. I won't trust security by obscurity. Sometimes publishing the code allows more people to watch it and find bugs before it is deployed in production.

Comment: I guess Remix wouldn't include it if it compromised sensitive metadata. I used this https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/deploy-a-simple-erc20-token-in-remix/1203

Answer (score 1):

If you want your contract's source code open and verifiable, you should publish the source and the metadata files on IPFS.

[Sourcify](http://sourcify.dev/) makes use of these to verify contracts. The bytecode of your deployed contract has the IPFS hash of the metadata file embedded. That means Sourcify or anyone can extract this metadata and fetch it from IPFS. The metadata also contains IPFS hashes to the source files and if they are also published, it is possible to recompile the contract and compare it against the on-chain deployed contract, therefore to **verify** it.